# What's the difference between 蝦 and 鰕?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, characters

I found there are two characters for "xia1" (ghra as in Middle Chinese), 蝦 and 鰕.

Could someone explain what the difference is?

Comment: http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE9ZdicB0Zdic95.htm

Comment: @JamesJiao both of them have the meaning of "shrimp". Which one should I use?

Comment: @MikeManilone You should use "虾"

Comment: @fefe Um. No, I mean which one of them, not the simplified one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use 蝦. As can be seen in [zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE9ZdicB0Zdic95.htm) 鰕 used to mean shrimp, but is not used anymore in this meaning. In Japan it however is still a common character.

Using Google:

- [蝦 site:tw](http://www.google.com.tw/#hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%E8%9D%A6+site%3atw&oq=%E8%9D%A6+site%3atw&gs_l=hp.3...12786.22078.0.23238.9.9.0.0.0.0.251.1012.5j3j1.9.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.hp.P0Jj0FTzGy4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k&fp=2504fab692a3f0a0&biw=1366&bih=643) has about 7,060,000 results
- [鰕 site:tw](http://www.google.com.tw/#hl=en&q=%E9%B0%95+site%3atw&oq=%E9%B0%95+site%3atw&gs_l=serp.3...81528.81528.0.81858.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.serp.LKEqni1coyQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k&fp=eccac1687bb4e61e&biw=1366&bih=606) has about 29,400 results

The latter is used in some exotic fish names.

Comment: Thanks for your Google idea. I have never thought up such an idea!

Comment: I can confirm seeing `蝦` on dozens of signs and menus in Taipei. I can't recall seeing `鰕`.

Comment: Let's put it this way, 鰕 is old, 蝦 is new. Use the new one although both are the same.

Comment: @MikeManilone you have to be careful comparing number of hits sometimes - there's lots of "incorrectness" out there. For example 的, 地, and 得.

Answer (score 2):

This can help you to distinguish 蝦 and 鰕 http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra03660.htm

> 蝦 蝦蟆也。蝦蟆見於本艸經。背有黑點。身小。能跳接百蟲。
>
> 蝦 the toad. The toad can be found in Compendium of Medical Herbs. It has black spots at the back. Small one. Can jump to catch many insects.
>
> 鰕 鰕魚也。三字句。各本作魵也。今正。鰕者、今之蝦字。
>
> 鰕 the shrimp. In three characters. (this is 說文解字 typical wording) Other book says this is a kind of spotted fish. Now is corrected to shrimp. 鰕, is the character 蝦 we use now.

so the character 蝦 came from 蝦蟆 (toad), but somehow it replaced 鰕 and become the right character. So if you want to have some shrimp, you should use 蝦.

Though I'm a native speaker, I'm still amazed that 鰕 is original character since I use 蝦 all the time. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score -1):

According to modern science, shrimp is not a kind of fish, and it is not even [Vertebrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertebrate)，so you shall use 蝦 rather than 鰕. Because 虫 usually used to build glyphs related to worm-like animals, and 魚 used for fishes.

Exceptions:

- [鯨 (whale)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whale) is not fish, but ancient people simply don't know!
- [蛇 (snake)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake) is vetebrate, but people just think it is a huge earthworm!

Comment: no, 虫 originally meant snake, but later it evolved to mean worm.

Comment: The old character for worm is 蟲, derived from 虫 (snake)

Comment: Pretty good. Funny too.